# Proof of condition fulfillment

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, combinations

The question:

An international society has 1994 members from 6 countries. The number of members from each country is arbitrary, but never 0. The members are numbered as 1,2,3...,1994.
Prove that there will always be at least one member whose number is the sum of the numbers of 2 other members of his own country, or twice as large as the number of one member of his own country.

Attempt at solution:

I have no approaches. Don't understand how to do it. However I feel that since the number of possible ways in which either condition can be fulfilled exceeds the ways one can place the countries (??), it is true.

A hint in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Is this from any RMO?

Comment: No idea. It might be, though.

Comment: Note: this is Problem 6 from the 1978 IMO

Comment: Oh my, it indeed is. Thanks for pointing that out. Now how do I close this question? (Done)